# Angular - Sync pasted text with model

Tags: html, angular, typescript, paste

I'm writing a custom component and I need to update the model when pasting some text into an input. I thought I could use `Renderer2`'s `setValue` function to do this but it doesn't seem to work the way I was expecting it to.

I've been trying to search for similar issues but surprisingly there doesn't seem to be anyone else who has stumbled upon this issue yet..

How can I sync the model with the pasted text?

Template:

```
<input #input [(ngModel)]="model" (paste)="onPaste($event)">
```

Component:

```
@ViewChild('input') input: ElementRef;

constructor(private renderer2: Renderer2) {}

onPaste(event: any): void {

  this.renderer2.setValue(this.input, event.clipboardData.getData('text/plain'));

  // Is not set with the new data
  console.log(this.model);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the `(paste)` event fires before the `(input)` event which causes the model not to be updated when the paste event fires. Which is why it's "not synced", I had to use `setTimeout()` in the paste callback to make it wait for the model update. After that I can get access to the model like you normally would.

You can also do it like this:

https://plnkr.co/edit/NFOwVzO5M5XzbwzHsVjA?p=preview

Cred to @Ghetolay for that solution.